# "Would fly" versus "would have flown"

Tags: grammaticality, past-tense, subjunctive-mood, past-perfect

I am not a native speaker of  English. Could anyone please tell me which sentence is correct?

> If I had money, I would fly to Spain.
>   If I had money, I would have flown to Spain.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, both sentences are grammatical, but they mean different things. It depends on what you're trying to say.

The first means, that if you had money, you'd fly there now or some point in the future.

The second can mean one of two things, depending on whether "had" is intended to be 'hypothetical' or a genuine 'past reference': so it could mean either (a) if you had money (now), you would at some point in the past have flown there; (b) if, at some point in the past being referred to, you had had money, then at that moment or some moment thereafter, you would have flown to Spain.

As I say, it's not really a question of one sentence being grammatical and the other not, rather that they have different interpretations.

Comment: How could you wish for something *now* that would affect your past?

Comment: You're not "wishing" for something as such. As a matter-of-fact statement, you're simply saying that if you were rich/had enough money, you would have flown.

Answer (score 3):

The following are correct (the second one is a correction of your second possibility)

- 'If I had money, I would fly to Spain' (present subjunctive)

This means that I probably don't have money now, but in the alternate universe where I do have money, I think I want to fly there.

- 'If I had had money, I would have flown to Spain.' (past subjunctive)

This means that, in the past, I probably didn't have any money, went to Spain by some other means, but in the alternate universe, the presence of extra money might have allowed me to indulge in flying.

Comment: thanks.. but cannot understand why 'had' has to be repeated

Comment: 'had' is both the simple past form and also the past participle. So to make a pluperfect, you end up with 'had had' (just as 'had eaten', 'had given' etc). You don't HAVE to use a pluperfect in this sentence-- the simple past that you have is also grammatical (and again the implication is slightly different).

Comment: Yes, I agree that you don't have to have the second 'had'. It sounds weird with two (a bit formal) but it is 'correct' and helps emphasize the difference. With a single 'had' it is ambiguous, but sounds more like the present subjunctive. Also, separately, to make the sentences sound just that tiny bit better, 'If I had -the- money,...' or 'If I had -enough- money,...' but the originals are still correct.

Comment: *If I had money, I would have flown to Spain,* means the same thing as *If I were rich, I would have flown to Spain,* while *If I had had money, I would have flown to Spain,* means *If I had possessed more money at the time I was considering a trip to Spain, I would have flown there.* The difference is in the timing of the lack of money.

Answer (score 0):

"If I had money, I would fly to Spain" means I don't have money now, but I imagine if I have money (now or in future) I would fly to Spain.

"If I had (had) money, I would have flown to Spain" refers a past incident. I had no money then, so I could not fly to Spain and I regret on that.

I think I am right. If any one has any other meaning, you may please explain.